# How would I go about adding definitions to my language?

Tags: c, interpreter

I have written a stack based interpreted language in C. The interpreter works with reading a file line by line and executing the line depending on the operation. `print(1 + 1)` in python would become `1 1 + print`.

Here is the function to check what the operation is and push it to the stack or do an operation on it:

```c
if (strncmp(op, "+", 1) == 0 && is_definition == 0)
{
    float a = pop(stack);
    float b = pop(stack);
    push(stack, a + b);
}
else if (strncmp(op, "-", 1) == 0 && is_definition == 0)
{
    float a = pop(stack);
    float b = pop(stack);
    push(stack, b - a);
}
else if (strncmp(op, "*", 1) == 0 && is_definition == 0)
{
    float a = pop(stack);
    float b = pop(stack);
    push(stack, a * b);
}
else if (strncmp(op, "/", 1) == 0 && is_definition == 0)
{
    float a = pop(stack);
    float b = pop(stack);
    push(stack, b / a);
}
else if (strncmp(op, "print", 5) == 0 && is_definition == 0)
{
    float a = pop(stack);
    if(a == (int)a)
        printf("%d\n", (int)a);
    else
        printf("%f\n", a);
}
else if (strncmp(op, "define", 6) == 0 && is_definition == 0)
{
    is_definition = 1;
}
else if (is_definition == 1)
{
}
else if (strncmp(op, "end", 3) == 0 && is_definition == 1)
{
    is_definition = 0;
}
else
{
    push(stack, atoi(op));
}
```

This is inside a loop that iterates over every space separated operation in the code.

I want to add a definition system a bit like the one in C.
This is the syntax I would like to have

```c
define TEST 10 end
```

I would like to use this a bit like a variable system where you can use `TEST`.

Comment: Note that calling strcmp in a nested if-else like this is very inefficient. You should place all strings in a sorted look-up table instead then binary search through that one.

Comment: Instead of having the whole `is_definition` thing, parse the `define` in full cmpletely in the `define` case. If you simplify it to only set a single variable and not need the `end` clause, you could use e.g. `sscanf` to parse the remainder of the line, as in `sscanf(remainder, "%s %d", name, &value)`. Then add the variable and value pair into some kind of symbol table, which you can search in the `else` case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pseudo code, you should do the following:

1. Read a line of source
2. If it is a definition, parse+store it and skip the rest
3. (it is not a definition) execute, much like the code you posted

About "parse+store" the definitions, you need - for example - a couple of arrays, or an array of structs. You need to store each "name" (the alias, or the name of the definition) and, along with each name, its value.

Then, in the code you posted, you should implement the push() instruction (you only mention pop()). The push() instruction reads an operand and determines if it is an alias (definition) or not:

(push pseudo code)

1. Get the operand
2. Determine if it is a definition. Basically, you iterate on all the stored definitions to find a correspondence
3. Got the final value, put it on the stack

There are several things that could be said... a couple of them, in sparse order:

- The pushed operand is a number? In this case you can skip the definition(s) checking, assuming that it is illegal to say "define 10 20"
- Would you allow to (re)define operators?
- Would you allow a definition to refer to other definitions?

...